# Android project version release automation

Tags: android, git, gradle, continuous-integration, release-management

How Android version release is made in your team? Do you have CI and what CI server do you use? How do you deliver versions to testing team?

Now when we need to build a version someone needs to

1. run gradle task
2. copy files to internal server
3. increase version in AndroidManifest
4. create git tag.

I want to automate this process. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Using Jenkins will fulfill your requirement.

Using combination of ANT and Batch files you can achieve your requirement:

**Set up Ant**

Install Ant if you don't have it already.

In your Eclipse workspace, run the following command to set up Ant for the app project:

```
android update project -p android-app
```

**Build File**

To generate build you can now run followinf command in your workspace:

```
ant clean debug
```

You can find more detail on this on following URL:

[Building an Android app and test project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+an+Android+app+and+test+project)

**Upload file to server**

Now to upload a file to internal server you can use FTP jenkins plugin: 
[Publish Over FTP Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+FTP+Plugin)

**Version Update**

To update version you can create an Ant XMl task to edit AndroidManifest file. Example:

```
 <xmltask  >
        <replace path="/manifest/@android:versionCode"
                     withText="Your Version" expandProperties="false" />
            <replace path="/manifest/@android:versionName"
                     withText="Version Name" expandProperties="false" />
        </xmltask>
```

**Create git tag**

To create Git tag we have a plugin in Jenkins named :**GIT Publisher plugin** [Git Plugins tutorial](http://www.benhallbenhall.com/2013/03/hudson-jenkins-create-git-tags-branches-automatically/)

I hope this will help.